# Broadcast to IceCast using Cordova/Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, broadcast, icecast

I want to broadcast sound data to an IceCast server using my hybrid application (Cordova / Ionic).

Where can I find the information needed to build a proper SHOUTcast/Icecast source client or a built library for this.

Thanks.